# std::sort c++ what is binary function

Tags: c++, function, sorting, binary, std

I am reading c++ reference site.

I don't understand what it mean? Give you explain to me what it mean and example of it

comp
    Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
    The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
    This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

Comment: "**that accepts two elements**"

Comment: Binary = something to do with two =D

Comment: What you mean was...   std::sort(begin(), end(), std::pair) which they will check for the pair.first?

Comment: @user2056901 `std::pair` is not a function.

Answer (score 10):

With regards to functions:

- **Nullary** - takes no arguments, e.g. `void nullary()`
- **Unary** - takes one argument, e.g. `void unary(int)`
- **Binary** - takes two arguments, e.g. `void binary(int, float)`
- **Ternary** - takes three arguments, e.g. `void ternary(int, float, char)`
- **N-ary** - takes N arguments

So a binary function is one that takes two arguments, such as `void foo(int x, float y);`. The comparison function passed to `std::sort` should be a binary function that takes two elements from the sequence you're sorting and returns a `bool`. If for example, you're sorting a sequence of `X`, the function should have the signature `bool compare(const X&, const X&);`.

Here's an example usage:

```
bool less_than(const int& a, const int& b)
{
  return a < b;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {5, 1, 2, 4, 3};
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less_than);
}
```

Here, `less_than` is a binary function that just returns true if the first argument is less than the second. This is precisely what `std::less` does. The power of `std::sort` is that it allows you to give *any* binary function that returns `bool` and it'll sort using that.